# Cell Swipe Works in One Project But Not The Other

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, uiscrollview

I took source code from a project and tried to implement it into mine. Unfortunately, it didn't work. After analyzing and reanalyzing, I found that the cell swipe only works on the source code file, but does not work on mine.

I copied the .h file into my project:

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DHSwipeAwayCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *leftView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *rightView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *centerView;

@end
```

and the .m file:

```
#import "DHSwipeAwayCell.h"

@implementation DHSwipeAwayCell

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
[super layoutSubviews];

CGRect frame = self.bounds;
self.scrollView.frame = frame;
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width*3, frame.size.height);

self.leftView.frame = frame;
self.centerView.frame = CGRectOffset(frame, frame.size.width, 0);
self.rightView.frame = CGRectOffset(frame, frame.size.width*2, 0);

[self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:self.centerView.frame animated:NO];
}

@end
```

I even copied the exact same cell into mine, but as soon as it was in my project, it stopped working. I linked the class to the cell. Everything looks completely the same in both view controllers. Maybe I have some settings changed in my project? I'm not sure why I have the same setup in both projects, but only one is working.

Comment: Did u connect the outlets in the xib?

Comment: @Norbert Yes. Everything's linked up.

Comment: clean and build the project.

Comment: @Norbert How do I do that?

Comment: in the Product menu u can find clean, build and run options.

Comment: @Norbert Still not working.

Comment: Then the problem is not with the above code. For me everything looks fine. May be the problem lies somewhere else. Try setting break point in the layoutSubviews and make sure the scrollview instance is not nil and also the rightview and leftview.

Comment: @Norbert How would I go about doing that?

Comment: just click on the line number below the layoutSubviews method.

Comment: @Norbert how would I know if it's nil?

Comment: either by using break point as shown in http://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=http://ios.biomsoft.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/bp3.gif&imgrefurl=http://ios.biomsoft.com/2011/11/09/xcode-4-debug-breakpoints-conditions-and-actions/&usg=__FWMD8qkudtdjhLWHdKJriT8tX3I=&h=290&w=474&sz=22&hl=en&start=4&zoom=1&tbnid=-NHgGZCue6jyzM:&tbnh=79&tbnw=129&ei=9cvTUZvTB8amrQf94oDoDw&um=1&itbs=1&sa=X&ved=0CDQQrQMwAw

Comment: or use NSLog(@"%@",self.scrollView); in layoutSubviews

Comment: @Norbert This is what I get when I use NSLog: <UIScrollView: 0xa1a6920; frame = (0 0; 320 44); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+TM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xa14e600>; layer = <CALayer: 0xa1a0a90>; contentOffset: {320, 0}>

Comment: set [self.scrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; and self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;

Comment: @Norbert No luck. Still doesn't work. :(

Comment: if i have access to code i can help out. GitHub?

Comment: @Norbert You can have access to the source code file. https://github.com/derrh/SwipeAwayCell. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: @Norbert But I didn't use a TableView. I edited the source code to only use a cell.

Comment: @Norbert Figured it out. Thanks for all your help last night.

Answer (score 1):

It was as simple as unchecking the "Use Autolayout" button!